in VSCode, how to set up a breakpoint if a gloabl variable value changes
In VSCode, I can set up a data breakpoint when a variable value changes.
On the left tab, VARIABLES->LOCAL, then right click, "Break On Value Change"
Can I do the same for global variable?
I can't even see the global variables from VARIABLES tab.
I can monitor it from 'WATCH' window, but right click from the "WATCH" windows doesn't show "BREAK ON VALUE CHANGE" option.
I have tried to set up break point, monitor the variables

what language? if c or c++, related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1410#issuecomment-1523509746
